# How to display value from TextBox into a MessageBox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a textbox named "txtNumSticks" where the user enters a number. After the user hits start, I want a message box to pop up that says "Okay! We'll play with (x) sticks!" But I can't get it to work. First day learning VB.net. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim NumSticks As String
    txtNumSticks.Text = NumSticks
    Game.Show()
    Me.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Okay! We'll play with " & NumSticks & "sticks!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the variable the wrong way around you should be assigning NumSticks to the value in the text box so:

```
NumSticks = txtNumSticks.Text
```

or alternatively without the use of a variable

```
MessageBox.Show("Okay! We'll play with " & txtNumSticks.Text & "sticks!")
```

Comment: Thank you! Switching the variable assignment worked! However, I also tried the second way you showed me without the variable, but it didn't work. Any idea why that wouldn't work? It just says, "Okay! We'll play with sticks!"

Comment: NumSticks = txtNumSticks.Text.ToString

Comment: `txtNumSticks.Text` does not need `.ToString()` applied to it as it is already a string.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to add a little bit of error checking in your program to make sure your value entered is Numeric.

```
    Dim NumSticks As String

    NumSticks = txtNumSticks.Text.ToString

    If IsNumeric(NumSticks) Then
        Game.Show()
        MessageBox.Show("Okay! We'll play with " & NumSticks & " sticks!")
        Me.Close()

    Else
        ' Let user know the value is non-numeric
        MessageBox.Show("Non Numeric Value entered", "Error!", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub

    End If
```

Comment: Awesome! I was actually just figuring out a way to do that too!

Comment: You should try getting familiar with Try..Parse..Catch..Finally as well. This with added logging saves so many headaches trying to solve where your code went wrong.